# 5-10V to 3V3 level converter for bidirectional I/O

Tags: level-shifting

I need connect 3V3 powered MSP430 family processor and PW0268 ultrasonic sonar IC. PW0268 is powered **Vcc 5-11V** and is connected with MCU via bidirectional *IO* pin which is internally pulled up (3.5-6.5k) to Vcc as there is an open colector transistor. When Vcc 10V I can measure Vio 7.7V (or 8.7V/6.7V). The function is: MCU generates short pulse, releases IO and sonar IC pull down when response is received. I cannot use my "standard" 74LVC shifter method as they are not tolerant to voltage above 5V. I'm uncertain about common base FET method used for I2C 5/3V3 shifting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT0QrH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My only idea is to use resistor and 3V3 zener diod but it will leak current which I dislike as it's battery powered circuit, use MOSFET transistor used with Vgs=5-10V, Vds=3V3 (but FET Vgsmax is normally 8V and I'm not sure about Vgs/Vds/Id diagram) or use an operating amplifier powered 3V3 with 12V tolerant inputs (if any).

Any idea how to do it simply and efficiently ?

**Edit:**
Level shift with Schottky diode blocking higher voltage in high state and small enough forward voltage (Vf@D2 + open Vce@Q2) to fill requirment for low state at input pin.

Comment: There are specialized chips for bi-directional level conversion. Google is your friend.

Comment: Absolutely, there are tons of specialized chips for any conversion in 1.8-5V range. But I'm asking for high-to-low shift beyond this range.

Comment: good point. if the timing permits, you could make the 11V->3V shifter much higher in impedance (say 100k/100k), with a (schottky) diode to the 3V power instead of the zener? If you choose an opamp, why not power it with the5-11V?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I've added Schottky option in original schema (do you meand this way?). I agree with opamp power but I believe opamp is too "complicated" for such a simple case.

Comment: Seems to me like the ancient CD40109 would work here. Still made. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40109b-q1.pdf